Hibernate Parent Child Mapping in Spring Boot Project
`Hello. I want to save the data I took from the Account Code Template table to the Account Code table. The data in these tables has a parent-child relationship (child can also be in the parent. I will add an example visual for your understanding). How can I follow a method to save the data I receive from the Account Code Template to the Account Code table? I share my entity classes.
public class HesapKoduTemplate extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(
        name = "PARENT_HESAP_KODU_TEMPLATE_ID",
        referencedColumnName = "ID"
    )
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private HesapKoduTemplate parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<HesapKoduTemplate> children = new ArrayList<>();

    private BirimType birimType;
    private String hesapAdi;
    private String hesapKodu;
    private Long ownerBirimId;

}


public class HesapKodu extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(
        name = "PARENT_HESAP_KODU_ID",
        referencedColumnName = "ID"
    )
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private HesapKodu parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<HesapKodu> children = new ArrayList<>();

    private String hesapAdi;
    private String hesapKodu; //Hesap Kodu + Ekonomik Kod , Path
    private Long ownerBirimId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT true")
    private Boolean active;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "BOOLEAN DEFAULT false")
    private Boolean genelPlan;
}

